# textarea placement is wonky

Tags: html, css

Why is my text area placement different than my input type="text" placement?

Snippet related.

```css
input[type="text"], textarea {
  height:100px;
}

/* no css other than height to show my point */
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Form 1, input type=text"/>
  <input type="button" value="Form 1"/>
  <input type="button" value="It is centered"/>
</form>

<form>
  <textarea placeholder="Form 2, textarea."></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Form 2"/>
  <input type="button" value="Not centered"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What is wrong about the placement?

Comment: The issue is that the button is placed all the way at the bottom of the text area, plus 50% of its self height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean its placement regarding the sibling inputs then you can set `vertical-align` for the `textarea`:

```
textarea {
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* the rest of your styles */
}
```

**EDIT:**

`Vertical-align` has default value of `baseline`.
The baseline for textarea is towards the bottom (if you have an inline-block div instead of the textarea it'd be the same). But baseline for `input[type=text]` - as it naturally has only one line - is in the middle. So we need to explicitly add `vertical-align: middle` for the textarea.

Comment: Hi Samurai. What do you think is causing the issue in the first place. Just looked at this with sample code and tested re checking re margin /padding etc and did not find anything. Thanks. JR

Answer (score 1):

I've made some assumption to try and best answer your question. Check out the code snippet and feel free to let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Basically, the reason that input buttons in the second form due not vertically align is because the textarea element does not adhere to the "height" attribute (the height attribute is not listed on W3C's site: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp).

The textarea uses the attributes cols and rows to define it's size.

Next, to position the input buttons such that they are vertically-centered, you can apply the following CSS:

```
  form.middleFloat textarea { vertical-align: middle; }
  form.middleFloat input,
  form.middleFloat textarea {display: inline-block; }
```

Snippet created for reference.

```css
      form { margin: 10px 0; }
      
      form.middleFloat textarea{
        vertical-align:  middle; 
        
      }
      form.middleFloat input, form.middleFloat textarea {
        display: inline-block;
      }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Form 1, input type=text"/>
  <input type="button" value="Form 1"/>
  <input type="button" value="It is centered"/>
</form>

<form class="middleFloat">
  <textarea cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="Form 2, textarea."></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="Form 2"/>
  <input type="button" value="Not centered"/>
</form>
```